# Web analytic with python

Tags: python, django, google-analytics, web-analytics

I want to build a web analytic as google analytics.

My requirement for this system that is high throughput, scalability, low latency and efficient ETL. And If it's ok, can we use Django to develop.

But I don't know which technique is suitable for my case.

For detail, I need to answer these questions:

**With Django, which open source is the best for **

1) Which framework can help me build high throughput, scalability, low latency service?

2) Which database is better for real-time as google's analytic: High Performance, Security & Permissions, Low Latency Storage, Fully Managed, Redundant Autoscaling Storage, Seamless Cluster Resizing, HBase Compatible.

3) Which Framework for ETL with high performance?

**Without Django/python, which language is the best and which is suitable question for these question above**

Thanks & Best Regards,

Jame

Comment: I highly suggest you use cloud services, for example i managed to resend the same request done to google analytics to my own app hosted in google app engine where i ll process the params of the request and store the hit in Big query. Ones you have the info saved its a matter of how efficient you can manage to make querys and calculate metrics. If you want more detail ask me. (I used python)

Comment: I knew google analytic, but I need to private web analytic. It's my mission. And I have to use python with any other technology.